# mask money not working on dynamically added inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm using **jquery.maskMoney.js** to add mask to the input it works for the normal input..but it's not working for the dynamically added input.
here's the code which i'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="demo['+x+']" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $('input[id^="demo"]').each(function () {
    $(this).maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true}); 
});


<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="demo[1]"></div>
</div>
```

kindly help i'm stuck

Comment: Pls replicate your issue with minimal working code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your javascript that way. See the `initMaskMoney()`, it's called both after page load and after text field addition. Also you don't need to iterate each element, you can use selectors select all at once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
     var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
     var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
     var x = 1; //initlal text box count
     $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
         if(x < max_fields){ 
             x++; //text box increment
             $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="demo['+x+']" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
             //re-init mask money to apply new added input 
             initMaskMoney();
         }
    });
     initMaskMoney();

});

function initMaskMoney() {
    $('input[id^="demo"]').maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true}); 
}

</script>
```

**Update**
After seeing @Dekel's answer I think this version is more convenient. `initMaskMoney` gets a parameter called selector. With the help of this parameter you can init maskmoney for current items and for only new added input only (in the previous answer all input boxes were initing MaskMoney again).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
     var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
     var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
     var x = 1; //initlal text box count
     $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
             x++; //text box increment
             var newItem =  $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="demo['+x+']" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>')
             $(wrapper).append(newItem); //add input box
             //init mask money for only added input
             initMaskMoney($(newItem).find('input'));
         }
    });

    //init mask money for current inputs
    initMaskMoney('input[id^="demo"]');

});

function initMaskMoney(selector) {
    $(selector).maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true}); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: i'm appending multiple inputs..i used only single input for example only..and your previous answer run perfectly for testing. but in my project it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Then you should post your "actual code" to find a better/common solution.

Comment: okkk i figured it out..thanks for helping..your code helped a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('input[id^="demo"]').each` will work on any **existing** elements, but will not work on new created elements. Your problem is that when you click on the button - you append new elements to the document, and on those elements you didn't initiate the `.hasMoney` plugin.
What you can do is after you append the new `<input` to your document - call the `.hasMoney` on that element.

You might wanna change a bit your code:

```
i = $('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="demo['+x+']" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>')
$(wrapper).append(i); //add input box
i.find('input').maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on focus on a field call function :

```
getDecimal2()
{

    $("#eupdate_property_luasNet").maskMoney();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the formating using .trigger('mask.maskMoney').

```
    $("#budget_prevision").maskMoney({
        prefix:'R$ ', 
        allowNegative: false, 
        thousands:'.', 
        decimal:',', 
        affixesStay: false          
    }).trigger('mask.maskMoney');
```